# Unity 2d - allow both keyboard and joystick

Tags: c#, keyboard, joystick, unity-game-engine

How to allow both keyboard and joystick controller as input in a same scene.
and yes, based on priority the other input should get locked.

Comment: I would suggest you read https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html to get a good understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, your project should be able to detect both keyboard and joystick input. See [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html) and [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html) for more info.

As for locking out one or the other, you can use the answer provided [here](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/131899/how-do-i-check-what-input-device-is-currently-beei.html) as a starting point, and then block the input not being used.

Ideally, you would want some way of switching between the two, like using the first command from the locked controller to unlock it and then handle input normally. Some games don't block, but rather let the user switch seamlessly between input types and update the UI accordingly. In the end it all depends on your game and what works best for you.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NYZoLOpYp2k

Video shows implementing an additional layer(Inputmanager) and handles the both.

EDIT: Or more simple one is keep the same name for both Joystick and Keyboard. for example, "Horizontal" this input would be created by default for both joystick and keyboard. so basically no need additional code to allow both controls.